# How to use jQueryUI draggable in LWC experience builder

Tags: lightning-web-components, experience-builder-page

I am trying to make a marker that will be working as a pointer to some specific place on the image of house plan/blueprint. I decided to use jQueryUI but cant get it to work in LWC. I want to use draggable for dragging a marker on top of the house plan. But still getting this error

> "ReferenceError: $ is not defined".

The code of the marker:

HTML

```html
<div lwc:dom="manual" class="lwc-manual" id="lwc-manual"></div>
<div class="container">
<div id="dragMe" class="draggable" onclick={dragIt}>Drag me</div>
</div>
```

JS

```javascript
import {api, LightningElement, wire} from 'lwc';
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import jQuery from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jquery';
import jQueryUI from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jqueryui'

export default class KreslenieDemo extends LightningElement {

renderedCallback(){
    loadScript(this, jQuery+ '/jquery-3.6.0.min.js')
        .then(() => {
            console.log('JQuery loaded.');
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            console.log('Failed to load the JQuery : ' +error);
        });
    loadScript(this, jQueryUI+'jquery-ui.min.js')
        .then(() => {
            console.log('JQueryUI loaded.');
            this.scriptsLoaded = true;
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            console.log('Failed to load the JQuery : ' +error);
        });
    }
    dragIt(event){
        $(this.template.querySelector('.draggable')).draggable();
    }
}
```

[image]